# match pattern in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I  have a dataframe like below,I am trying to do in python. The dataframe is formed after reading csv with the product information . The input can be of two format
1)

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| X | Key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 |
| Y | Key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 |

2)

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| X | [ Key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 |
| Y | [ Key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 |

In the product series I have key, value pairs

I want to store only the values of key3 in a series and remove the remaining key's and it's values.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'''
    [\S]+:                
    (?:
    \s                    
        (?!\S+:)\S+       
    )+                    
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

re.findall(r'key3', str(datadfnew2['Product']))
```

I tried to match pattern as above which is not working

I want the output to look like,

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| X | val3 |
| Y | val3 |

Please help me do that.
Thanks

Comment: Some more info would be helpful: What language are you using and what code is used to create the dataframe (particularly, what format is it in)? What exactly do you want the output to look like (including format)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question right, if the series is key value pair then the output text can be easily extracted by using the key as below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}],
                'Y': [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}]}).T

df_new = df.rename(columns={0:'Products'})

df_new['ProductsNew'] = df_new['Products'].apply(lambda x: x['key3'])
```

This will save the 'val3' in new column.